# boost::counting_iterator analogue in range-v3

Tags: c++, boost, range-v3

I am wondering if [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library has any view/utility providing the functionality similar to [boost::counting_iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html)?

I was looking for something of that kind, but seems there is nothing readily available. But the documentation is incomplete (at least the README suggests so) so maybe there is something I have overlooked.

UPD: what I am actually looking for is not just a range of integers like view::iota but rather a range view (wrapper) that accepts any Incrementable.
One such example is the following code from Boost.CountingIterator documentation:

```
int N = 7;
std::vector<int> numbers;
...
// the code below does what I am actually looking for
// I would like to use a single range instead of two separate iterators here
std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> pointers;
std::copy(boost::make_counting_iterator(numbers.begin()),
          boost::make_counting_iterator(numbers.end()),
          std::back_inserter(pointers));
```

Comment: So you want the opposite of view::indirect? The doc for iota says it works with any incrementable type, although the end might be inconvenient to specify in some cases.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, it turned out view::iota fits in here just fine. I was sort of misunderstanding it as only working with integral types, but it appears to do just the right thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `view::ints` is what you're looking for. You can make an unbounded range, and truncate it with something like `view::take`:

```
using namespace ranges;
int x = accumulate(view::ints(0) | view::take(10), 0); // 45
```

or you can make a bounded range (lower inclusive, upper exclusive)

```
int x = accumulate(view::ints(0, 10), 0);
```

For your example, you can use `view::iota` instead.

```
copy(view::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()), back_inserter(pointers));
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, unfortunately this is not quite what I'm looking for. While view::ints and view::iota indeed generate sequences of integers, the counting_iterator is more versatile - it can accept any Incrementable, i.e., another iterator, so that by dereferencing it you'll be getting that iterator back. This is basically what I'm trying to get here as well. Let me put this into an update to the original question.

Comment: @Argenet: In that case, `view::iota` will work fine. I added an example that does exactly what the example in your question does.

Answer (score 4):

You do, in fact, want `view::iota`. It accepts any `WeaklyIncrementable` type for the range iterator type (not only integral types), and any type that is `WeaklyEqualityComparable` to that type as the range sentinel. So `view::iota(0, 8)` is the range of integers `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`, and `view::iota(i, s)` is the range of iterators `{i,i+1,i+2,...,s}`. The boost `counting_iterator` example translates to range-v3 as ([**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5mlNUefDKKt9skA4)):

```
int N = 7;
std::vector<int> numbers = ranges::view::iota(0, N);

std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> pointers =
    ranges::view::iota(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

std::cout << "indirectly printing out the numbers from 0 to " << N << '\n';
ranges::copy(ranges::view::indirect(pointers),
    ranges::ostream_iterator<>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << '\n';
```